# Setting up a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-access

I would like to do something like create "virtual LAN" over the internet.

The local machine is a computer connected to a LAN, which has about 10-15 peer-to-peer computers connected. Now I want to add another P2P connection to the existing LAN from a remote location. All windows XP machines.

Is this possible?

Do VPNs allow for this kind of a set up? If so are there any tutorials I could follow/readings I could do so I could set up one?

Is there any **free** software which allows this?

Thanks

P.S. I don't know if this is the right stack exchange site to ask the question on, mods move/close as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of connection do you have to the remote network? You can use a program called Hamachi from LogMeIn in a Gateway configuration. Basically, you will have a gateway machine on each end. Each computer will connect to the other remote location gateway which will allow full network resource access to the nodes connecting to the remote gateway. Likewise on the other end, you will have each of those nodes connect to the other gateway machine; allowing full network resource access.

The nice thing about this kind of configuration is that you will not be opening up any ports on your firewall which could present security risks if not properly handled.

The downside of Hamachi is that it uses a 100Mbps virtual NIC. If you have an pipe between the two remote connections greater than this then you may want to look into another solution.

Comment: The remote network is all connected by a Netgear fs608 switch.
Sounds like Hamachi is a shareware, does it have a trial period or restricted functionality?

Comment: The restricted functionality is 8 connections per network. However, you can create two Gateway Networks on each gateway which would allow a total of 14 computers from a remote location to connect to your network. Add a third Gateway network and have 21 users. Hamachi is free for personal use up to 8 clients per Hamachi Network. A single computer can have more than 1 hamachi network. If you need a computer with more than 8 Gateway connections, you could create a VM cluster of Gateways on a machine. I've been using the free version of hamachi for personal use for 6 years.

Comment: Oh, btw. 1995 called and and wants "shareware" back. :)

Comment: dont get the reference...was too young at the time :P
also edited my question

Comment: this wont work for long, this setup is for a small business which is expanding so I will need user activity logs, more connections, user specific permissions

Comment: Do you need this to be Peer-2-peer? Traditional VPN does not suit your application?